# Use python3 selenium on tor onion domains not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried to connect to tor service with python3  selenium and privoxy as reverse proxy.
the issue is that its not seems to be recognize the .onion domain name, and im gotting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=https%3A//www.bbcnewsv2vjtpsuy.onion/&c=UTF-8&d=We%20can%E2%80%99t%20connect%20to%20the%20server%20at%20www.bbcnewsv2vjtpsuy.onion.
```

I'm using this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver

browser = None

proxy_address = "127.0.0.1:8118"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': proxy_address,
})

tor = '/usr/bin/firefox'
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(tor)

def get_browser(binary=None, proxy=None):
    global browser
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    if not browser:
        # set tor profile
        ff_profile = FirefoxProfile("/home/seltest/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/")
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ff_profile, executable_path="/home/seltest/geckodriver",firefox_binary=binary, proxy=proxy, options=options)
    return browser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = get_browser(binary=firefox_binary, proxy=proxy)
    browser.get("https://www.bbcnewsv2vjtpsuy.onion/")
    print(browser.page_source)
```